# CompletableFuture.supplyAsync vs new CompletableFuture()

Tags: java, completable-future

I don't understand what's happening here with CompletableFuture/supplyAsync.

If I invoke the `supplyAsync` method from a CompletableFuture object previously instantiated, it never completes:

```
public static void ex1() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
   final CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
   cf.supplyAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println("Main.m3");
      return "Main";
   });
   System.out.println("Start: cf = " + cf);
   final String value = cf.get();
   System.out.println("End: value = " + value);
}
```

This is the output:

```
Start: cf = java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@5b480cf9[Not completed]
Main.m3
```

As you can see the `System.out.println("End: cf = " + cf);` is never executed.

To make it running I need to put a `complete(my value)` inside the body of the supplyAsync.

**But** if I directly invoke the `supplyAsync` while creating the CompletableFuture (or by calling the static `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`):

```
public static void ex2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
   final CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>()
      .supplyAsync(() -> {
         System.out.println("Main.m3");
         return "Main";
      });
   System.out.println("Start: cf = " + cf);
   final String value = cf.get();
   System.out.println("End: value = " + value);
}
```

It works as expected. You can see here the output:

```
Start: cf = java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@5b480cf9[Not completed]
Main.m3
End: value = Main
```

So my question is: why this? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

`supplyAsync` is a `static` method that returns a new `CompletableFuture` and it should not be called via an instance.

In the **first case**, you are calling `get()` on a `CompletableFuture` that **never started** anything.

In fact, you'll notice that your program when calling `ex1()` will remain in a `pending` state forever. And because of this, it can never execute the next line, which prints the result `Main` (of the other `Future` that computed in parallel).

The point, is that you do not store the second `CompletableFuture` anywhere. So there is no way you'll be able to call the **correct** `get()`.

---

In your **second case** you are building the instance with the return value of `supplyAsync`, and you store it in `cf`. And this is the right way to construct a `CompletableFuture`. (the `new CompletableFuture<>()` part is superfluous; in fact, you assign it a new instance right away with `supplyAsync`).

When you call `get()` you therefore wait for the right `CompletableFuture` to return its result.

Comment: Yep, I was in a hurry and totally missed the `static` method :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier<U>)` is a static function, so in ex1 you are allocating a `CompletableFuture` but never using it.

From java 8 source:

```
/**
 * Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed
 * by a task running in the {@link ForkJoinPool#commonPool()} with
 * the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.
 *
 * @param supplier a function returning the value to be used
 * to complete the returned CompletableFuture
 * @param <U> the function's return type
 * @return the new CompletableFuture
 */
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier) {
    return asyncSupplyStage(ASYNC_POOL, supplier);
}
```

in your case ex1 should be:

```
public static void ex1() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Main.m3");
        return "Main";
    });
    System.out.println("Start: cf = " + cf);
    final String value = cf.get();
    System.out.println("End: value = " + value);
}
```

and ex2 is the correct format but you get there by accident, by allocating a new `CompletableFuture` and calling a static method, but in ex2 you do not discard the returned value while in ex1 you do.

In you ex1 and ex2 you are effectively calling the same method, the code I provided above for ex1 is correct for both cases where you call static correctly using class name and not discarding the returned object.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The key here is the 'static' method. I didn't notice it :-)

Comment: @CarloAlbertoDegliAtti not quite: calling `get()` on an incomplete `CompletableFuture` is the key. Because it blocks the execution flow. Calling a `static` method via an `instance` does not alter the result although it's not how things are done

Comment: @payloc indeed. By quoting I was referring the 'supplyAsync' method in general (I was not intending that being static it's the problem).